# No sound when making calls with iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm using iPhone 6. Sometimes when I answer a phone call, there's no sound. Only when I answer again or call back can I hear the voice. Does anyone else have the same problem? Do you know the reason?

Comment: Depending on your cellular signal, this can happen sometimes. Is the signal good in your area?

Comment: Not perfect, but good. If that totally depends on cellular signal, why i can answer the calls with no problem the second time i answer the call?

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear. It doesn't totally depend on the cell signal. If the problem is still persisting o would take it in to the Apple Store if it is still covered.

Comment: Make sure your volume's up and your phone isn't muted.

Comment: Have you tried restoring the software on the phone? This can fix a lot of software-related problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so common but it has happened to all of us.  It's usually due to a glitch in the cellular communication which can happen at any signal strength. It's of course possible that the person on the other end of the phone hit their mute button too.  In any case if you are not able to reliably repeat the problem then it is due to some random occurrences in the cellular network and not anything within your control.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, check to see if your network uses wifi calling. I've noticed a slight to moderate delay when it uses wifi voip when on a supported network. Especially at home. It is a godsend though as my cell service is bad there but internet is fast.